# Numpy: set all values of a matrix to the right of the maximal value in each row to the maximal value in that row

Tags: numpy

Basically, I am looking for the numpy primitives which will accomplish the following for loop impementation:

```
# for a matrix M
argmaxes = np.argmax(M,axis=1)

for i,arg in enumerate(argmaxes):
  M[i,arg:] = M[i,arg]
```

Is there a numpy-ish way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following doesn't use `for` loop, but it creates several intermediate arrays of the same shape as `M`. So I'm not sure how efficient it is over loop:

```
maxes = np.max(M, axis=1)

M = np.where(np.arange(M.shape[1]) > argmaxes[:,None],
         maxes[:,None], 
         M)
```

Comment: seems like it is on the right track; maybe this is an opportunity for `@numba` too

Comment: Time test this.  For the small example in the delete `np.maxium.accumulate` answer, this is slower than the OP.  I don't know why the `accumulate` answer was deleted.  It is fast.